# Variable that is never used

Tags: java, android

I have this block of code where my app, supposedly, when the user inserts a right password and a right email, goes to the main activity, although when I used the `run` method, it says that the variable is never used.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
    mAuthTask = null;
    showProgress(false);

    if (success) {
         public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Second.class));
            finish();
        }
        finish();
    } else {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
        mPasswordView.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact error/warning message

Comment: It says “variable is never used”

Comment: It should say that a specific variable is never used. Where do you use `mAuthTask`?

Comment: mAuthTask is not used in this block. Don't know anything else from your description

Comment: mAuthTask is used right here: ```mAuthTask = null```.  I assume it's a member variable, so that seems perfectly reasonable.  The question remains, which variable is never used?  I see nothing declared but unused, so it's likely we're not looking at actual code.  A secondary question: what is the "it" that says the variable is never used?

Comment: Some IDEs will report variables that are assigned but never read as unused. So it wouldn't surprise me to see `mAuthTask` reported as unused.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have incorrect code in your method. Take a look at the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
    ...

    if (success) {
         public void run() {
            ...
        }
        finish();
    } else {
       ...
    }
}
```

You have a block of method named `run()` which is incorrect. So, you need to remove it. Your code should be something like this then:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
    mAuthTask = null;
    showProgress(false);

    if (success) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Second.class));
        finish();
    } else {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
        mPasswordView.requestFocus();
    }
}
```